# Simultaneously replace list of strings with a single value

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

I want to replace a list of strings with a single string in a pythonic way. To clarify what I mean, this code does what I want:

```
my_string = 'abc'
list_strings = ['a', 'b']
for replace_string in list_strings:
    my_string = my_string.replace(replace_string, 'c')
```

I would have imagined though, that

```
my_string = my_string.replace(list_strings, 'c')
```

would have done the trick. But the `replace` method only accepts a string as input.

Is there a more pythonic way (I imagine, a way without a `for` cycle) to perform this operation?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On solution could be to use regular expression (see [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub)):

```
import re

my_string = 'abc'

list_strings = ['a', 'b']

pattern = '|'.join(list_strings)
output = re.sub(pattern, 'bc', my_string)
print(output)
#  bcbcc
```

note: I modified the replacement string to `bc` to show a case leading to a different output

Comment: Nice! Thanks for the answer, +1